# Why do cockroaches and flying beetles survive high levels of radiation?

Tags: entomology, radiation

Apparently it's a fact that [cockroaches survive nuclear radiations](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7912/can-cockroaches-survive-a-nuclear-war/7915#7915).

How can they survive this?

Comment: I'm puzzled by your comment that humans are invulnerable to insecticides. Dosage is key; organophosphate poisoning is pretty common (and it is a pretty common insecticide.)

Comment: They survive radiations because of their slow cell replication, Humans are NOT invulnerable to pesticides at all. Most pesticides will have really negative effects on humans, and can cause deaths in certain concentrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cockroaches have slow cellular replication rates and radiation is known to be the most dangerous to replicating cells, thus making cockroaches (and several other insects) more resistant to radiation than us, but not immune.

This was the subject on a [Discovery episode of MythBuster](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/cockroaches-survive-nuclear-explosion/)